How to copy files from one dir to another
I am trying to copy files from one folder to another.
With this code:
Sub test()
Dim fso

Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemObject")

fso.copyfile "C:\test\s\test.xlsx", "C:\test\t"

Set fso = Nothing


End Sub

I get:
Run time error 70, permission denied. 

What is the error with this code?
